# Factorial function output not displaying, won't grab value from textbox

Tags: javascript, html

The code I am trying to create runs a function that takes whatever value you put in the text box and factorializes it. It worked fine when I had it grab values from a prompt, but now that I am trying to make it look a little more neat and take values from a text box, it gives me a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error and won't perform correctly. I am thinking I have issues with the function finding the text box value and inputting it in the function.

```js
window.onerror = function(message, url, line, col) {
  console.error("Error: " + message + "\nURL: " + url + "\nLine: " + line + "\nColumn: " + col);
  return true;
};
var x = document.getElementById("factortext").value;
function factorial(x) {
  if (x === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return x * factorial(x - 1);
}
console.log(factorial(5));
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = factorial(x);
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Factorialize!</h1>
<input type="text" id="factortext" name="factor" value="Input Number here!"></input><br><br>
<button onclick="factorial()">Submit</button>
<p id="display"></p>
```

Comment: there is an error in your code

Comment: @Lokesh: Perhaps you could be a bit more specific? :-) I mean, I'm guessing he *knows* there's an error in the code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yea I could but I guess the OP is beginner so I want him a chance to debug this code and taste a bit of debugging

Comment: what you want your `onclick` do?

Comment: Zacharias - FYI, that `window.onerror` function is unnecessary on browsers that support `console`. They'll show an uncaught error in the console *anyway* (and usually make it possible to click that error to go right to the code that generated it).

Comment: I'm pretty aware there is an error in the code, and my teacher advised me to post it here to get help. I've been working on trying to fix this for the last week or so with no progress, so I am here. Also, the window.onerror is required for the class.

Answer (score 1):

You need a callback function. Just have that function call the factorial.

Your original `onClick` function did not have a parameter coming into it.

```js
window.onerror = function(message, url, line, col) {
  console.error("Error: " + message + "\nURL: " + url + "\nLine: " + line + "\nColumn: " + col);
  return true;
};

console.log(factorial(5));

function factorial(x) {
  if (x === 0) return 1;
  return x * factorial(x - 1);
}

function calculateFactorial() {
  var x = document.getElementById("factortext").value;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = factorial(x);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Factorialize!</h1>
<input type="text" id="factortext" name="factor" placeholder="Input Number here!" />
<br><br>
<button onClick="calculateFactorial()">Submit</button>
<p id="display"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you answered my question, fixed my code, and taught me stuff in the process. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the value as soon as your script runs, not later when the button is pressed. Instead, set up a separate function that is called when the button is pressed, getting the value from the input *then*, converting it to a number, and then calling `factorial` and showing the result. (E.g., most of your existing code, wrapped in a function called by the button click.)

Comment: Exactly. You need to move the line `var x = document.getElementById("factortext").value;` inside the function, and you should also convert it to a number with `x = parseInt(x)` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has already been given by others above, I'm just going to explain why you ran into an infinite loop.

When you click the button, your code (`<button onclick="factorial()">`) invokes `factorial()` with no arguments. This means that, inside the function, `x` will be `undefined`. Now, on your first line, you check for strict equality: `(x === 0)`. An undefined value is not strictly equal to zero, so your function doesn't exit here; instead, it moves on and tries to subtract 1 from `undefined`, which results in `NaN` ("not a number"). Then, it invokes `factorial()` with `NaN` as the parameter. Again, `NaN` is not equal to 0 (the defining characteristic of `NaN` is that it's not equal to anything, not even itself!), so your function doesn't exit, but instead goes on to subtract 1 from `NaN`, which results in -- you guessed it: `NaN`. And so your function goes on forever, until the call stack overflows.

If you check for a "falsy value" in the first line:

```
if (!x) return 1;
```

then your function will return 1 if invoked without arguments. A falsy value can be 0, `undefined`, `null`, an empty string, or `NaN`.